# MYSQL Count occurrences of item that may occur in any column of any row

Tags: mysql, select, count

I have a table for requested items:

```
Date, Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4
```

Item# will contain SKU numbers and not the actual words.

You will see things like this:

```
09/13/2022, Stapler, Tape, Glue,
10/02/2022, Screws, Nails, Hammer, Screwdriver
12/12/2022, Paint, Brush, Dropcloth, Roller
01/12/2023, Glue, Tape, Stapler
03/23/2023, Roller, Brush, Paint, Dropcloth
04/14/2023, Screwdriver, Paint, Glue, Screws
```

I have no control over what items are entered in what order and there 100+ items.

I want to count how many times each sku occurs and how long since last requests

```
Hammer, 2, n_days
Stapler, 2, n_days
Paint, 3, 22
```

Comment: which version of mysql are you using?

Comment: You should normalise your table. What happens if more than four items are requested? A simple table of the form `Date, Item` would allow as many, or as few, items to be requested as needed, as well as simplifying the queries. The one answer currently posted  will become unwieldy if you have to allow for 100 items to be requested.

Comment: You really have 100+ columns with ``items``? May be your table is (Date date, items varchar(1000))? where items contains comma separated SKU list.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select t.it as 'item' , count(*) as 'count' , timestampdiff(day , min(t.date) , max(t.date)) as 'n_days'
from 
(
    (select date , item1 it) UNION ALL
    (select date , item2 it) UNION ALL
    (select date , item3 it) UNION ALL
    (select date , item4 it)
) t
group by t.it
```

Comment: Supposing there are more than four items requested. OP suggests that there are 100 or more different items that might be asked for. Your solution implies potentially a union of 100 sub queries.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular In the case of 100 (but fixed) items or columns, I propose to use a while loop to create the query `@qry` and then execute it as a dynamic query like `PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;`

Comment: I bet that won't be quick..